# Unexpected changes to InRelease (on gb.archive.ubuntu.com)

Tags: apt, updates, security, repository

On running `sudo apt update` I've just been issued the following warnings:

```
E: Repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'code stable' to 'Ubuntu'
E: Repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'code stable' to 'Ubuntu'
N: Repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '' to '22.04'
N: Repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable' to 'jammy-updates'
E: Repository 'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' changed its 'Codename' value from 'stable' to 'jammy'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]
```

I can't find any notice of these changes - and frankly don't know where to look - but as that inrelease file contains the checksum for the packages I'd be installing I'm loathe to blindly accept it, as that file being changed breaks the chain of trust for the underlying packages.

Does anyone have an official source referring these changes, or an idea of where I can get an official comment on whether these changes are safe to accept?